# FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) - firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

```
I/flutter ( 4737): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter ( 4737): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter ( 4737): ^
```

This is the complete error I got.
This is the part of code where i am making a post request.Please note that `CustomExeption` is my own error and I am handling it in other part of my app.

```
Future<void> signup(String email, String password) async {
    final url =
        "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:SignUp?key=[API_KEY]";
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            "email": email,
            "password": password,
            "returnSecureToken": true,
          },
        ),
      );
      if (json.decode(response.body)['error'] != null) {
        throw CustomException(
          json.decode(response.body)['error']['message'],
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;//Han
    }
  }
```

This is the part of the code which is triggering the above method

```
  Future<void> _saveForm() async {
    if (!_form.currentState.validate()) {
      return;
    }
    if (_isSubmitted == false) {
      await Provider.of<Auth>(
        context,
        listen: false,
      ).signup(
        _new_user.getEmail,
        _new_user.getPass,
      );
      setState(() {
        _isSubmitted = true;
      });
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to proceed.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are ya using URLs and primitive APIs for signing up in firebase? There's a package and a procedure for that...

Comment: @rkdupr0n I have already used firebase_auth package. This is just a test project,where I am trying to play around and learn other stuff about flutter.

Comment: Hmm... Pls tell me you put ur API key in that url.